# Change Hbase size limit

Tags: hbase

I have in one of my tables one of the rows exceeding the default size of 64MB. Now whenever I try to scan that row or delete it this error shows up:

> ERROR: Protocol message was too large.  May be malicious.  Use CodedInputStream.setSizeLimit() to increase the size limit.

I've tried changing in hbase-site.xml hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize to 256MB and it has no effect.

I've also tried with no luck to change it from the shell directly with

```
CodedInputStream.setSizeLimit(268435456)
```

How can I change this limit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an open jira for this:

> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-13825

You can **comment** on jira for ETA or workaround.

Comment: Have a look at this comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-11747?focusedCommentId=14097370&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14097370

Comment: Sorry for the delay @AnilGupta, how do you exactly do CodedInputStream.setSizeLimit() in the client? I can't find a way to call setSizeLimit()

Comment: @Marco facing a similar issue. Were you able to find any solutions to this

Comment: @mayooran In the end I ended up doing configuration.setLong("hbase.client.scanner.max.result.size", 2147483648L)