# How to set the column family size for a Hbase table column family?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, column-family, bigdata

I am trying to import data from a CSV file into a HBase table. But I am running into the below shown exception during the import.

```
Error: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message was too large.  May be malicious.  Use CodedInputStream.setSizeLimit() to increase the size limit.
        at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.sizeLimitExceeded(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:110)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.refillBuffer(CodedInputStream.java:755)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.isAtEnd(CodedInputStream.java:701)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readTag(CodedInputStream.java:99)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto$ColumnValue$QualifierValue.<init>(ClientProtos.java:8599)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto$ColumnValue$QualifierValue.<init>(ClientProtos.java:8563)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto$ColumnValue$QualifierValue$1.parsePartialFrom(ClientProtos.java:8672)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto$ColumnValue$QualifierValue$1.parsePartialFrom(ClientProtos.java:8667)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:309)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto$ColumnValue.<init>(ClientProtos.java:8462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto$ColumnValue.<init>(ClientProtos.java:8404)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto$ColumnValue$1.parsePartialFrom(ClientProtos.java:8498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto$ColumnValue$1.parsePartialFrom(ClientProtos.java:8493)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:309)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto.<init>(ClientProtos.java:7959)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto.<init>(ClientProtos.java:7890)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto$1.parsePartialFrom(ClientProtos.java:8045)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto$1.parsePartialFrom(ClientProtos.java:8040)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:200)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:241)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:253)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:259)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto.parseDelimitedFrom(ClientProtos.java:10468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.MutationSerialization$MutationDeserializer.deserialize(MutationSerialization.java:60)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.MutationSerialization$MutationDeserializer.deserialize(MutationSerialization.java:50)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.ReduceContextImpl.nextKeyValue(ReduceContextImpl.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.ReduceContextImpl.nextKey(ReduceContextImpl.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.nextKey(WrappedReducer.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$NewCombinerRunner.combine(Task.java:1651)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:700)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:770)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

I believe it has to do with the data length higher than the default size. How can I increase the column family size of the HBase column through the terminal? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To alter column family block size

```
alter 'my_table', {NAME => 'my_cf', BLOCKSIZE => '1048756'}
```

Then call `describe 'my_table'` to see table meta info and verify that it worked.

Comment: Thanks man, I was able to set the blocksize this way. But still I'm getting the above shown exception. Are there any other sizes that I need to alter? Any ideas? :(

Comment: @mayooran seems that you're hitting default 64Mb limit. here's question on the same topic  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158900/change-hbase-size-limit

Comment: it says that version 1.02 fixes this issue. What I am using is 0.98. Guess will have to update. Thanks man! :)

Answer (score 0):

if it has a single column family  to change it cell number use below command 
alter 'table' NAME=> 'column family' , VERSIONS => number